# How do I stop a $interval function to execute if the server has not responded yet?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest

Let me clarify the question:

I have a function in my controller that uses a service to send an HTTP GET request to see if the status is 'done'. This function runs every 5 secs. However, this would also run in every 5 seconds even if there is no response yet, without killing the previous request.

How do I ensure that if there is no response, in 5 secs, that the previous request is killed? Or is there a better solution to this?

Here's my $interval function:

```
self.$interval(function setInterval() {
    EngineService.getEngines().then(
      function getEngines(response) {
        self.enginesListFromDatabase = response;
        for (const item of self.enginesListFromDatabase) {
          if (item.status === 'done' && self.doneArray.indexOf(item.id) === -1) {
            self.doneArray.push(item.id);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }, self.interval);
```

The service has this http call:

```
  getEngines() {
    return this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/engines',
    }).then(
         function getResponse(res){
           return res.data;
         }
       );
  }
```

I tried looking into the docs, but couldn't make sense of how to use $interval properly for this case, or $q.

Comment: I don't want the entire $interval process to stop though, I just want the previous request to 'die' or something if there is no response in self. interval time. So that the response to the second request never comes back before the response to the first request.

Comment: Why do you care if the previous request is cancelled or not? You're still getting your response.

Comment: Because if I send request #1 at 11am, and the server gives me "Not done", but does not send the response back in 5 mins. When I send request # 2 at 11: 10 am, and the server responds quickly and tells me "done". After this, the response to request #1 comes back saying "Not done". I would think that that it became "not done" later, not the other way.  Tell me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Won't happen that way if you set timeout for $http

Answer (score 1):

You can create a $promise and save it to  EngineService for canceling requests.

```
EngineService.canceler = $q.defer(); // $q is a service u need to inject to EngineService. this is just example that u should assign it to the service
getEngines() {
    return this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/engines',
      timeout:EngineService.canceler
    }).then(
         function getResponse(res){
           return res.data;
         }
       );
  }
```

and cancel the last request:

```
self.$interval(function setInterval() {
    EngineService.canceler.resolve();
    EngineService.getEngines().then(
      function getEngines(response) {
        self.enginesListFromDatabase = response;
        for (const item of self.enginesListFromDatabase) {
          if (item.status === 'done' && self.doneArray.indexOf(item.id) === -1) {
            self.doneArray.push(item.id);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }, self.interval);
```

Comment: Do you know how I can test if this works? The server works very fast every time I try, so I can't really test if this is working.

Comment: Are u mastering the server? Maybe you could manual add some delay in your server-side code.

Comment: If you can't modify the server, you could add a delay using a proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) by putting a breakpoint on the request.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your cancelling the request approach - I think it would be much easier to have a variable in your controller (or service) that holds the done/undone status. That way, in each function in the `then(..)` section, you can ask:

```
if (!self.done) { 
    ...
}
```

And then get on in case that's relevant. Otherwise, all requests' responses would fail at that if and nothing would happen, nothing gets overridden.

To cancel future requests -

You can make use of `$interval.cancel` method and cancel your interval when you're getting your response.

```
var intervalFunc = $interval(function () { 
        ... 
        if (!self.done && gotMyWay) {
            $interval.cancel(intervalFunc); 
        }
    }, self.interval);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6848/) demonstrating the cancel mechanism.